# get value from checkbox using php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I use ajax and jquery to append the uploaded image div with checkbox to the thumbnails div  which located inside the form, then I when I click the "move marked to set" button it should direct me to the viewset.php page, but I can't get the value from the checkbox, what did I do wrong, can anyone help, thanks!

here is my jquery ajax code

```
  $('#thumbnails').append('<div id="imagediv' + str_idnum + '"    style="width:520px;border: 2px solid #aaa;text-align:left;padding:20px;margin-     bottom:20px;"><div><img src="' + response + '" style="padding:10px; margin-right:20px; border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;border-left: 2px solid #ccc;border-top: 2px solid #ddd; border-right: 2px solid #ddd;"  id="imageid' + str_idnum + '" align="left"/></div"><div class="descriptionwrapper" style="border: 0px solid #aaa;"><textarea cols="40" rows="3" id="textarea' + str_idnum + '" onClick="SelectAll(\'textarea' + str_idnum + '\')" align="left" style="resize:none;">Optional description goes here...</textarea><br /><input   type="checkbox" style="" name="check[]" value="checked" id="check' +str_idnum + '"/>Mark<br /><br /><br /></div></div>').fadeIn();
```

here is my html code

```
   <form id ="complicated" method = 'post' action = 'viewset.php'>

     <div class="fancybuttonwrapper" style="margin-left:480px;">
      <input type="submit" class="form_button" id="movetoset" value="  Move Marked to  Set"></div>
       <div class="images" id="thumbnails">
     </div> 
    </form>
```

here is part of my php code:

```
$check =  $_POST['check'];
$N = count($check);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
   echo( $check[$i] . " ");                            
}
```

Comment: what is it outputting if anything? Looks like the value of check  should == 'checked'? Does print_r($_POST['check']); show anything?

Answer (score 0):

You're only posting the DOM manipulation.
If you edit your question and add the actual AJAX call I'd be more than happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean to get value from the checkbox? If you would like to know if checkbox is checked or not, you can use this example.

In this example When you check each checkbox they will toogle `#ToggleDivId`

//HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkIt(this);" name="check[]" value="checked" id="check' +str_idnum + '"/>
```

//JS

```
function checkIt(objectt) {$('#ToggleDivId').fadeToggle(objectt.checked);}
```

Hope it helps...